# NullPointerException on an array of an objec

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, polymorphism

I have a bankaccount super class and two subclasses extended from it, checking and savings. Im suppose to create an array of bankaccount but everytime I reference it, it throws me a NullPointerException. Why is it doing this? Please try to dumb this one down for me.

```
public void newAccount() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please create an account id:");
    readid = br.readLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < baArray.length; i++) {
        baArray[i]=new Bankaccount();
        if (baArray[1]==null) {
            System.out.println("its null!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `baArray`?

Comment: When you are checking `if (baArray[1]==null)`, your for loop has just created `baArray[0]`, so `baArray[1]` is still null. Move the check behind the closing `}` of your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `NullPointException` because you are initializing `beArray` every time you enter the `for` cicle and you are trying to access item `1` of a `null Bankaccount();`
The first element of an array is 0.
Change `1` to `i` in

```
if (baArray[1]==null){
```

and you will have an array full of `null BankAccount();`
Btw, where are you initiliazing `beArray`?